# Difficulty Optimizing Postgres Write Throughput

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6, write-ahead-logging

I'm trying to index a collection of roughly 127K files using a
PostgreSQL 9.6 server on RDS. I had expected the process of writing these
documents to the DB to take about 8 hours, but over time I observe
that the write rate decays to 0 so that the process doesn't
complete (at some point, inserts begin timing out). Unfortunately, I don't have much DBA/PostgreSQL background,
so I'm struggling to debug this.

On average, indexing one file means inserting 125 rows and 0.5 MB
of data into a table (some files are significant
outliers, yielding ~40K rows). I have some uniqueness constraints on the table and would prefer to avoid introducing them later, if possible.

Initially, the max WAL size on the database was set to 2 GB. My
automation could process roughly 25K files before insert performance
became unusable, with acceptable write throughput during the first
hour. Increasing the max WAL size to 30 GB helped, but didn't completely solve the problem; with this configuration the system was able to index 85K files before the insert rate degraded. Looking at the
database logs, I saw primarily checkpoints that started due to the
configured timeout (15 minutes). On the RDS console, I see a fairly
consistent average write throughput of 5-15 MB / sec.

Eventually I may need to index a larger corpus of ~635K files, so I'd
like to find settings where I get consistent write throughput.

Database Specifications:

- PostgreSQL 9.6.15 (on RDS)
- 6 TB disk
- 4 CPU
- 16 GB RAM
- Max WAL size: 30 GB
- Checkpoint Timeout: 15 min.
- Checkpoint Completion Target: 0.9

Questions:

- Do I need to increase the configured max WAL size again? Is there a rule of thumb for how large this should be?
- Why did a 15x increase in max WAL size only increase the amount of files I could index by 3-4x?
- Are there other places I should look for diagnostic information?
- If I stop the write process temporarily and restart it hours later, write performance improves temporarily. Why is this?

Clarifications:

- The database instance is a db.m4.xlarge.
- The 6 TB of disk on this database is general purpose SSD.
- The current timeout for the transaction that stores a single file's data is 15 minutes. My tests suggest this should be ample to process any individual file.
- What I wrote originally about indices was not completely precise. I need to enforce some uniqueness requirements on a handful of columns, and would prefer to avoid introducing this constraint after the table is populated, if possible.

Comment: Feels like your I/O performance is degrading over time. Perhaps your provider throttles I/O after a while?

Comment: "I have several indices on the table (I don't think I can avoid these, due to other requirements)."  If your system doesn't function, it is hard to see what those other requirements could be that would override this.  Can you build the indexes later?

Comment: What kind of instance?  What kind of storage (6TB of what?).

Comment: "at some point, inserts begin timing out"  Who set the timeouts, and why?